# R: wireframe like 3D plot for categorical variables

Tags: r, graphics, graph, lattice, wireframe

I want to develop wireframe like plot with non-numeric on X, Y axis however numeric in Z axis.

```
# mydata 
set.seed(123)
yv <- rnorm(20, 10, 3)
gen <- rep(paste("G", 1:5, sep= ""), 4)
env <- c(rep(c("CA","MN","SD", "WI"), each = 5))
mdf <- data.frame(yv, gen, env)
```

I tried using lattice:

```
require(lattice)
wireframe(yv,gen, env, data = mdf)

Error in UseMethod("wireframe") : 
  no applicable method for 'wireframe' applied to 
  an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
set.seed(123)
mdf <- data.frame(yv=rnorm(20, 10, 3),
                  gen=rep(paste("G", 1:5, sep= ""), 4),
                  env=c(rep(c("CA","MN","SD", "WI"), each = 5)))
library(lattice)
wireframe(yv~gen*env,data=mdf,scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to use the functions in `lattice` is to use the formula interface.

Assuming that `yv` is your independent variable:

```
wireframe(yv ~ gen + env, data = mdf)
```

[image]